# create virtual host on ubuntu,

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, php

i  am new in PHP and i want to create my first PHP project but when i create virtual host on Ubuntu 18.04 and i try to change my PHP file, it doesn't change in my virtual host. I created my virtual host in Ubuntu by this way: first i created my directory:

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/www/myhost.local.co
```

after that i created another directory on it :

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/www/myhost.local.co/firstproject
```

and then i enter this command to have permission to insert my project file in it:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/myhost.local.co
```

and then i inserted my project in this directory and for setting up appache on ubuntu i change /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf by this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName myhost.local.co
DocumentRoot /var/www/myhost.local.co/firstproject/
<Directory /var/www/myhost.local.co/firstproject/>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and in my etc/host files i edit it and insert 127.0.0.1 myhost.local.co in it.at the end, i restarted my Apache :

```
$ service apache2 restart
```

after these commands my virtual host can work well and i can change my PHP project and i don't get any error but it doesn't have any affect in my output. for example when i comment one part in my code that part shows in my output

Answer (score 0):

This likely has nothing to do with the virtual host. A virtual host only points a browser at a directory (e.g. for your PHP project). It doesn't (meaningfully) govern what is displayed (e.g. your rendered PHP code does that).

It *may* have something to do with your browser caching web pages. The idea behind this is that the browser can look at a local cache of recent pages it has displayed and "ideally" serve a given web page "faster" if it pulls up a (sometimes outdated) page, rather than asking your server to resend the page (with your now updated code).

In general, whenever you make changes to a web page, you should clear your browser cache before reloading that page in your browser to avoid this.